# eventOpenTrigger function does not return event summary details in event object response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, gsuite-addons

In appsscript.json file, when eventOpenTrigger action triggers, onCalendarEventOpen function will be called.

```
 "calendar": {
       ....
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE", 
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventOpen"
      },
      "eventUpdateTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onCalendarEventUpdate"
      }
    }
```

In onCalendarEventOpen, I have done console log for getting event details information.

```
function onCalendarEventOpen(e){
  ...
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  ...
}
```

From console.log, I am able to get below data, which contains reference, attendee etc. details, but it does not contain event name, summary, time, location details.

```
{"calendar":{"capabilities":{"canSeeConferenceData":true,"canSeeAttendees":true,"canAddAttendees":true,"canSetConferenceData":true},"calendarId":"xyz@gmail.com","organizer":{"email":"xyz@gmail.com"},"id":"2a2gdhrpmcpm8rmav4s2sam8nc"},"userCountry":"","userLocale":"en","hostApp":"calendar","clientPlatform":"web","commonEventObject":{"userLocale":"en","hostApp":"CALENDAR","timeZone":{"offset":19800000,"id":"Asia/Kolkata"},"platform":"WEB"},"userTimezone":{"offSet":"19800000","id":"Asia/Kolkata"}}
```

How can I get event name, description and other event related details in eventOpenTrigger?

Comment: Read [Google Calendar Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events) Pay attention to item 5.  If that doesn't help to answer your question I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*You can make a `Calendar.Events: get` call to get the information of the event, using the information provided in the event object.*

#### Code Snippet:

Using the `CalendarApp` service of Apps Script:

```js
function onCalendarEventOpen(e) {
  var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendarId).getEventById(e.id);

  Logger.log(event.getTitle());        // Event name
  Logger.log(event.getDescription());  // Event description
}
```

Or, using the Calendar Advanced service:

```js
function onCalendarEventOpen(e) {
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(e.calendarId, e.id)

  Logger.log(event.summary);      // Event title
  Logger.log(event.description);  // Event description
}
```

Make sure to enable the Calendar Advanced service if you use this option, from the `Resources > Advanced Google Services...` menu item in the Apps Script UI.

#### References:

- [Class `CalendarEvent` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)
- [`Events.get` | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: You have mistaken in your first approach (CalendarApp), need to access the calendar object first: 

 var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendar.calendarId).getEventById(e.calendar.id);